# AttributeError: 'Car' object has no attribute 'describe_battery'

Tags: python-3.x

```
class Car:
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes of car"""
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
    
    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        """Displaying car descriptive name"""
        print(f"Car model : {self.model.title()}")
        print(f"Manufacture Date: {self.year}")
        print(f"Car name : {self.make.title()}")
        
class ElectricCar(Car):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """
        Initialize attributes of the parent class.
        Then initialize attributes specific to an electric car.
        """
        super().__init__(make, model, year)
        self.battery_size = 65
        
    def describe_battery(self):
        """Printing statement describing battert size """
        print(f"Your car battery {self.battery_size} kWh battery.")

name = Car('tesla', 'tesla X78', 2021)
print(name.get_descriptive_name())

name.describe_battery()
```

Comment: Why do you assume that ``Car`` has a method ``describe_battery`` in the first place? You have only defined it for ``ElectricCar``.

Answer (score 0):

`Car('tesla', 'tesla X78', 2021)` creates an object of type `Car` (not `ElectricCar`). Objects of this class don't have the `describe_battery` method, as per the class' definition, but objects of `ElectricCar` do.

You probably meant:

```
name = ElectricCar('tesla', 'tesla X78', 2021)
```